# Is it possible to cluster a sc-RNAseq expression matrix with weighting or embedding?

Tags: scrnaseq, clustering

I have an RNAseq mouse retina gene expression matrix(24659,49300) to cluster effectively. Here is a sample(7,4):

```
gene            cell1   cell2   cell3
KITL            0       0       1
TMTC3           3       0       0
CEP290          1       3       0
4930430F08RIK   2       1       2
1700017N19RIK   0       0       0
MGAT4C          0       0       4
```

Is there any chance to apply a weighting schema or embedding to increase ARI, NMI or DBI? Dataset is Macosko, 2015: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE63472

I want to try a new approach to cluster rnase data. Question is effectiveness to use weighting schema or embedding. Is it worth to try? May be someone tried it before.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.